# How to read data from input txt file into 2 C++ arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

The txt file

`1 2 3 4 5 col A`
`2 3 4 5 6 col B`
`2 3 4 5 6 col C`
`2 3 4 5 6 col D`
`2 3 4 5 6 col E`

I already know how to store the numbers into 2d array. However, the question also require me to store the words (including the space) into a one-dimensional array. Can somebody tell me how to do this? I am new to C++. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just post text, not images of text. And post the code you have so far.

Comment: So you can read into a 2D array. How is it any harder to read into a 1D array? Any *specific* problems?

Comment: @BoPersson I need to know how to make the code skip the number columns and read the "col A" ,"col B"etc into 1D array.

Comment: Post your working file into int[][] code, and a sample of data that it succeeds with.

Answer (score 0):

This would require a basic reading file loop which will read the file line by line, then split it by spaces. For the number it pushes it to the 2d array and the words to a 1d array:

```
fstream file;
file.open("somefile.txt");
vector<vector<double>> nums;
vector<string> words;
string line;
while(getline(file, line))
{
    vector<double> tempNums;
    istringstream liney(line); int i = 0; string cell;
    while(getline(liney, cell, ' '))
    {
       if(i < 5) tempNums.push_back(stoi(cell.c_str()));
       else words.push_back(" " + cell); 
       i++;
    }
    nums.push_back(tempNums)        
}
```

Hope this helps. (This is based on the formatting above)